# Simplify $5(3 \sin(x) + \sqrt3 \cos(x))$

Tags: trigonometry

So Wolfram tells me I can reach $10 \sqrt3 \sin(x + π/6)$ from this expression, but I cant grasp how to do it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Use $\cos(\pi/6)=\sqrt{3}/2$ and an additition formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know

$$\sin (x + a) = \sin x \cos a + \sin a \cos x$$

While we have

$$15 \sin x + 5 \sqrt 3 \cos x \tag {*}$$

Therefore if we can find an numbers $a, C$ such that $15 = C \cos a$ and $5\sqrt3 = C\sin a$, we can rewrite $(*)$ as

$$C \cos a \sin x + C \sin a \cos x = C\sin (x+a)$$

To find appropriate $C$ and $a$, notice that we have a system of two equations

$\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
C \cos a = 15 \\ 
C \sin a = 5 \sqrt 3 \\
\end{array}
\right.$

Square both sides of both equations and add the resulting equations. We get:

$C^2 \sin ^2 a + C^2 \cos ^2 a = 15^2 + 25 \cdot 3$

$C^2(\sin^2 a + \cos^2 a) = 300$

$C^2 = 300$

$C = 10 \sqrt 3$

Now subsitute in one of the equations

$10 \sqrt 3 \sin a = 5 \sqrt 3$

$\sin a = \dfrac 12$

$a = \dfrac {\pi}{6}$

Another possible value for $a$ is $\dfrac {5 \pi}{6}$, but only $\dfrac {\pi}{6}$ satisfies both equations.

Answer (score 4):

$a \sin x + b\cos x$

let $\phi = \arctan \frac{b}{a}$

$\sin {\phi} = \frac {b}{\sqrt {a^2+b^2}}\\
\cos {\phi} = \frac {a}{\sqrt {a^2+b^2}}$

$a \sin x + b\cos x = \sqrt {a^2 + b^2} (\cos\phi \sin x + \sin\phi\cos x) = \sqrt {a^2 + b^2} \sin (x+\phi)$

Answer (score 1):

its $$10\sqrt3\left(\frac{\sqrt3}{2}\sin{x}+\frac{1}{2}\cos{x}\right)=10\sqrt3\left(\sin60^{\circ}\sin{x}+\cos60^{\circ}\cos{x}\right)=10\sqrt3\cos\left(60^{\circ}-x\right)$$

In your case it's
$$10\sqrt3\left(\cos30^{\circ}\sin{x}+\sin30^{\circ}\cos{x}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

Given these identities:

$$\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{3} = \cos(\frac{\pi}{6})$$
$$\frac{1}{2} = \sin(\frac{\pi}{6})$$

$$\sin(\alpha + \beta) = \sin(\alpha)\cos(\beta) + \sin(\beta)\cos(\alpha)$$

We get:

$$5(3\sin(x) + \sqrt{3}\cos(x)) = $$

$$5\sqrt{3}(\sqrt{3}\sin(x) + \cos(x)) =$$

$$10\sqrt{3}(\cos(\frac{\pi}{6})\sin(x) + \frac{1}{2}\cos(x)) =$$

$$10\sqrt{3}(\cos(\frac{\pi}{6})\sin(x) + \sin(\frac{\pi}{6})\cos(x)) =$$
$$10\sqrt{3}\sin(x + \frac{\pi}{6})$$

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Didn't think on swapping $\sqrt3$ back into a cosine. Thanks.

Comment: @dxiv Oops, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

$$5(3sin(x)+\sqrt{3}cos(x))=10\sqrt{3}(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}sin(x)+\frac{1}{2}cos(x))=10\sqrt{3}(sin(x+\frac{\pi}{6}))$$